# mod_rewrite so a specific directory is removed/hidden from the URL, but still displays the content

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, directory

I'd like to create a rewrite in .htaccess for my site so that when a user asks for URL A, the content comes from URL B, but the user still sees the URL as being URL A.

So, for example, let's say I have content at mydomain.com/projects/project-example. I want users to be able to ask for mydomain.com/project-example, still see that URL in their address bar, but the browser should display the content from mydomain.com/projects/project-example.

I've looked through several .htaccess rewrite tips and FAQs, but unfortunately none of them seemed to present a solution for exactly what I've described above. Not everything on my domain will be coming from the /projects/ directory, so I'd imagine the rewrite should check to see if the page exists first so it's not appending /projects/ to every url. I'm really stumped.

If a rewrite is not exactly what I need, or if there is a simple solution for this problem, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial should have everything that you need, including addressing exactly what you are asking: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html . It may just be a matter of terminology.

> So, for example, let's say I have content at mydomain.com/projects/project-example. I want users to be able to ask for mydomain.com/project-example, still see that URL in their address bar, but the browser should display the content from mydomain.com/projects/project-example.

With something like:

```
RewriteRule ^project-example$ /projects/project-example [L]
```

When someone requests http://mydomain.com/project-example and the URI `/project-example` gets rewritten internally to `/projects/project-example`. Note that when this is in an .htaccess file, the URI `/project-example` gets the leading slash removed when matching.

If you have a directory of stuff, you can use regular expressions and back-references, for example you want any request for http://mydomain.com/stuff/ to map to `/internal/stuff/`:

```
RewriteRule ^stuff/(.*)$ /internal/stuff/$1 [L]
```

So requests for http://mydomain.com/stuff/file1.html, http://mydomain.com/stuff/image1.png, etc. get rewritten to `/internal/stuff/file1.html`, `/internal/stuff/image1.png`, etc.

Comment: The code example you provided (`RewriteRule ^project-example$ /projects/project-example [L]`) worked for displaying the content at `/projects/project-example` when asking for `/project-example`, however it worked like I would expect a redirect to work. The URI displayed in the browser was `mydomain.com/projects/project-example` instead of `mydomain.com/project-example` after the rewrite. Maybe something is interfering or I'm missing something? I'll continue researching and reading through the rewrite guide you provided to see if I can wrap my head around it. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like there's a trailing slash issue, apache wants to redirect things that look like directories to one with a trailing slash if it's missing. Try adding trailing slashes to the rule: `RewriteRule ^project-example/$ /projects/project-example/ [L]`